# Laravel5.5 after use php artisan app:name Class not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.5, laravel-artisan

I am new developer on Laravel, now I'm using Laravel version 5.5

I got the problem after used php artisan app:name on my project, I got the problem:

> In ProviderRepository.php line 208: Class
>   'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider' not found

as the captured image below:

[image]

As this error, I can not use php artisan commands or composer commands anymore can you guys please help me to solve this problem I am really appreciated for time. Thanks you

Best Regards
Siripong Gaewmaneechot

Comment: If you've opened it, you might have appended something to the name space, added a space before <?php or removed the entire opening php declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking in your config files, and the main classes which were generated when you started your laravel project (User class, etc) because they are all set to App\User App..... etc.

So for example, in the image you have in the question, it says it can not find App\AppProviders... - This indicates that somewhere you still have a use statement pointed to App\AppProviders.. but you changed the app name, so it's no longer App. ***something I do if I made that mistake, is I do a global search in my project files for App\ (you may need to put App\\ in the search because \ is an escape character***

So if you did not change the app name immediately after starting the project, some of the paths will not be pointing to the correct directories. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Hi Jake Boomgaarden, actually this project has been starting over a month and I just changed the application name and this caused the problem as I mentioned above.

Comment: Right, so when you run the laravel command to change the application name, it does not update every file you have with the new app name. It only will update specific default files. Because of this, you need to manually go through your application now and find all the places where you have a 'namespace' or 'use' statement that starts with App\ and change it to be your new project name. I believe that will fix your issue. Oh, and probably also in something like config/app.php

Comment: Hi Jack I just have done a global search **'App\'**  as you suggest through my folder but I still got the same thing happen T^T*.

Answer (score 0):

The command changes the PSR-4 configuration in `composer.json`.

Assume it was `App` before, your `composer.json` looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

After running the command with `php artisan app:name Foo`, it will look like:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Foo\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

Therefore the whole namespace has changed and your classes can't be found by the Autoloader. To fix this, you have to either go back to the old name or do a global search and replace to change the namespace from `App` to `Foo`.